# sending facebook app invitations

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm new to Facebook Android SDK 3.6.0. I made a new facebook app for my android application and sent app invitations to some of my friends. then I noticed that some people don't receive my invitation. even if they receive my invitation, they don't get any notification but the invitation is there on the https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/requests page. So can anyone explain me the reason for this? i used [HelloFacebookSample](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/HelloFacebookSample) to create login, share and invitation sending parts.

Comment: Well I've found something. People those who already connected with "Facebook for Android" gets my invitation as a push notification on the notification bar. Others receives it as a normal invitation on their facebook requests page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've found something. People those who already connected with "Facebook for Android" gets my invitation as a push notification on the notification bar. Others receives it as a normal invitation on their facebook requests page.